# echo product quantity in cart woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I want to display product quantity in the cart, on a single product page as text.

This is currently what I'm using in functions.php, I want to display the quantity number between.

```php
add_action('woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_form', 'gripsquantity', 5);
function gripsquantity(){ 
    echo 'Choose ';
    echo 'Grips';
}
```

So it will be "choose 3 grips" or "choose 1 grip" depending on the product quantity in the cart

Comment: You need js, jquery for that. And since its specific per website you need to provide atleast url so someone to write it for you.

Comment: Another way that may work for you not sure is to use woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_quantity to output **Choose** and woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_quantity to output **Grips**